# Is it possible to convert a settler ship into a settlement without moving and then build or is it considered a move?

Tags: catan, catan-explorers-pirates

Is it possible to purchase a settler during the build and trade phase, then load him onto a ship, move him, and then **on a next turn** convert him into a settlement during build phase?

Or is it considered to be a move and can it be done only during the movement phase?

Edit:

The things I find confusing are:

- Manual says: you can not build after moving phase (spend resources) with exception of converting because it does not cost resources
- Manual doesn't say I can not convert during build phase
- Manual says I can convert anytime when my ship points hex
- Manual says I can build a ship on a hex occupied by pirate ship without paying tribute because its not moving (so why converting would be moving ?)

So based on this info I would assume that I can convert setter ship into settlement during my build phase if it is in a correct position already, and then I could upgrade and/or build other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Converting a settler to a settlement is done as part of the **movement phase**, and can't be done during the **build and trade phase**.

This restriction to the movement phase can be missed in the English version of the rules because the sectioning is somewhat unclear;
luckily we can clarify things a little using the title in the [German version of the rules](https://www.catan.de/sites/default/files/2021-07/CATAN_EuP_Spielregel.pdf): **bewegungsphase: siedlung mit siedlerschiff gründen** or *Movement phase: Establish a settlement with a settler ship*.

[as a general rule](https://www.catan.com/faq/explorer-pirates):

- In the **build and trade phase** you do things for which you need
  resources.
- In the **movement phase** you do everything for which no
  resources are needed (*exception: buying additional movement points for wool*)

Comment: Can you provide quotes from manual, on which this rules are based ? Updated the question with parts I find confusing.